# Hi All, I have a partial view that I've using to pass a dynamically created script to the index. having issues with Escape Chars

Tags: html

Hi I'm trying to build a dynamic gannt chart

Index View consists of the model that Contains a Partial View

The partial view contains the DATA script for the chart.
If I just have the plain script it works no problem.
This I want to build dynamically from my sql data.

If I have the text as below like I said no issues.
The moment I put it in a loop and use write to output the data, I get this in the source   view

{start: '2023-10-01',end: '2023-11-18',name: 'Write new content',id: "Task 1",progress: 50,dependencies: 'Task 0'},

the single quotes turn in to `&#x27;`  and the quotes turn in to `&quot`
I've tried all sorts of escape chars and replaces, but can't seem to find the right combination.

This it what I'm using

```
@if(Model != null)
        {
            foreach(var Data in Model)
            {
                Write("{");
                Write("start: '2023-10-01',");
                Write("end: '2023-11-18',");
                Write("name: 'Write new content',");
                Write("id: \"Task 1\",");
                Write("progress: 50,");
                Write("dependencies: 'Task 0'");
                Write("},");
            }
        }
```

This is what I would like to generate

```
<script>
    var tasks = [
        {
            start: '2023-10-01',
            end: '2023-11-18',
            name: 'Write new content',
            id: "Task 1",
            progress: 50,
            dependencies: 'Task 0'
        },
        {
            start: '2023-10-01',
            end: '2023-11-18',
            name: 'Apply new styles',
            id: "Task 2",
            progress: 50,
            dependencies: 'Task 1'
        }
    ]
```

Thanks